# Azure Table Storage InsertOrReplace result

Tags: .net, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

When performing an `InsertOrReplace` operation on Azure Table Storage, is there any way to determine whether the entity was freshly inserted or if a replace occurred?

```
TableOperation insertOperation = TableOperation.InsertOrReplace(entity);
TableResult result = table.Execute(insertOperation);
```

`TableResult` does not seem to indicate this.

Comment: I don't think so. I'm curious why you would want to know that.

Comment: For auditing reasons.

Comment: I see. Thanks. You could implement `InsertOrReplace` on your own if you would like to do auditing rather than relying on Table Storage `InsertOrReplace` functionality.

Comment: If audit is requirement that my approach would be to have an Immutable storage. Meaning that once something is in the Storage, it stays there and does not change. If something needs to be update - a new version is created and the old still stays. Or as Gaurav mentioned, create your own version of InsertOrReplace where you first log what happens (and check for existence) and then add new record or update an entity

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`InsertOrReplace` will result with `HttpStatusCode.NoContent` on a successful insert or replace.  This is a slight deviation from HTTP that suggests 201 (`HttpStatusCode.Created`) should be the result if something is created or inserted.

Comment: it depends on your `prefer` vaue of HTTP request header. 
If the Prefer header is not specified or if it is set to return-content, then a successful operation returns status code 201 (Created). 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179433.aspx

Comment: That's true only for `Insert` but not for `InsertOrReplace`. `InsertOrReplace` will always return `204 NoContent` [see documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh452242.aspx)

Comment: I downvoted because as b2zw2a pointed out, the answer is simply incorrect. I even tested this on the off-chance the documentation was wrong. If you call InsertOrReplace, then result.HttpStatusCod‌​e == (int)System.Net.Http‌​StatusCode.NoContent, which is a 204 and this is the result regardless of whether you're adding a new row or updating an existing row. At the very least, the answer should say it's not possible because it will never return a 201. The given answer is misleading.

Comment: @MikeTaber Fair enough, and my response was originally what HTTP suggested the responses should be.  I've clarified the answer since I can't delete a response tagged as an answer.